# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

kindly please tell me jquery components are not working which libraries should i have to import for jquery Mobile

Comment: Maybe if you post your code for the called libraries, what libraries are you trying to import, etc etc?

Comment: With jQuery-Mobile version 1.3.1, use jQuery version 1.8.3 or higher. It's recommended to use jQuery version 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, your question isn't really the clearest ever ^^. If what you want is import jquery-mobile, use this line :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

It appears you are trying to apply a property to a non-existing Object, please post some code if your problem isn't solved.